# using google web fonts on mac computer

Tags: macos, webfonts, google-font-api

I'm building a web page that uses Google WebFonts (open sans) on a PC and it works perfectly, but when I try it on a mac computer it shows a question mark within the text. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Can you show how exactly you implement the request to Google Fonts? I guess it might be something with the `script` selection.

Comment: Thanks @udondan...My web app was built on a JAVA framework so I used this java annotation
@StyleSheet({"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,700"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character you are seeing is the [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character), which is used when a font does not contain a particular Unicode character, in this case, "ñ" AKA U+00F1 AKA "Latin small letter n with tilde".

Google Open Sans does contain this character, so it seems that Safari is not correctly getting the font from the web. The rendering engine is then reverting to another font, and that one is missing the offending character. You will be able to check in dev tools on your mac which font is being grabbed by your script.

I checked the script annotation you posted in the comment to your question. You are returning the fonts in the woff2 format.  It turns out that [woff2 is not supported in Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2) as of version 9, but [woff is](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff). I therefore recommend changing the format to woff and serving it to your page locally:

- Download the script you posted (http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,700)
- Save it as a css file (e.g. fonts.css)
- Find-and-replace woff2 to woff
- Save the file
- Add it to your web project (however you add your other files)
- Replace `@StyleSheet({"fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,700";}‌​)` with a reference to this newly uploaded file.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan...How can I change from woff2 to woff?I'm kinda lost there...I checked your link and woff2 is supported by chrome but I get the same replacement character..

Comment: I see it is not supported prior to Chrome 36 - perhaps you have an old version or perhaps caniuse is specifically referring to Chrome for Windows and not Chrome for iOS.  I have updated the answer with more details for how to change the format of the font.

Comment: Usually the Font API serves up a version in a format that will work with the browser by looking at the user agent. Is it possible that you are spoofing the UserAgent on the mac to something other than Chrome for iOS? Have you tried it in other browsers? (Safari, Firefox, IE, Opera?)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Thank you very much @Ivan...I did not, actually, it is courios that when I check code created on a PC in my mac in Eclipse I have have the same problem with spanish strings, so I'm really confused here on how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Solved! One of the developers had its Eclipse not set to UTF-8 so the file transfer using Git wasn't working properly...to check, go to Preferences>General>Workspace>Text file encoding and set to UTF-8