# Fonts in eclipse fail from Mac to PC or viceversa

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, fonts, bitbucket

I had a problem [using google fonts in a mac computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927994/using-google-web-fonts-on-mac-computer), but I realized that I have the same problem in Eclipse. We are a team that develops java code in both PCs and Mac using Bitbucket. Our problem is that all the strings with special characters fail o each other's computers. So for example, if I write "Español" in my Mac, de PC user sees "Espa?ol" and once fixed, when I pull his code, I also get "Espa?ol"

Any idea on why is this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Unlike mac and linux, windows has a different way or format for manipulating special characters or symbols (to my knowledge, if someone can correct me I would be appreciative). So that is your issue because how you declare the symbol ñ on mac is much different when declaring it or writing it on windows.

Comment: Thanks @Colin ...Is there a way to solve this? I assume that everyone o codes in Windows and uses a Linux server will have the same problem when using special characters...

Comment: Well being mac native I have no idea and haven't worked closely with this nor have I wrote a program like yours. I'm sure you can find plenty of resource online just from browsing google.

Comment: What encoding are you using for the Java files? You want to use something like UTF-8 which is the same across the different platforms.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 ...we are using UTF-8 in all platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! One of the developers had its Eclipse not set to UTF-8 so the file transfer using Git wasn't working properly...to check, go to Preferences>General>Workspace>Text file encoding and set to UTF-8